# prevent IE's default action on drag and dropped files open

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have Drag & Drop control in my webpage, whenever user accidentally drops files other than the control drop area say on IE it opens file. I want to disable that behavior by preventing it to open except on my Drag & Drop control in web page. I have tried following without any luck.

```
<body nmousedown="event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false" >
```

Note: I am using only IE8,IE9

Comment: I think you're missing an "o" in "nmousedown"

Comment: Thanks for pointing at, in real i have complete onmousedown.  Sorry could not notice it while copying. Still no success, i am not using HTML5

Comment: Any thought how to disable default action of IE

Comment: No, sorry. This is all I can find: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756583/prevent-browser-from-loading-a-drag-and-dropped-file?rq=1

Comment: This has supported only on HTML5 i guess, i am not using HTML5... Can you suggest any other alternatives.

Comment: The only other option I can think of is to try handling the default event with [jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

Comment: And attaching the event to the body tag on load