# Disable dragging images from desktop to html

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I was trying to implement a simple HTML5 drag and drop image uploader and everything worked nicely. I have a small div inside html with a simple js event handler which looks like this

```
$('#uploader').on('dragover', function(e){
  ...
}).on('dragenter', function(e){
  ...
}).on('dragleave', function(e){
  ...
}).on('drop', function(e){
  ...
})
```

The only small problem is that if a person missed that div and accidentally drops his images outside of it, the browser makes its default event (opening the image in the same tab), which is not really nice.

I tried to disable this by doing

```
$(elem).on('drop', function(e){
    if (e.originalEvent.preventDefault) e.originalEvent.preventDefault();
    if (e.originalEvent.stopPropagation) e.originalEvent.stopPropagation();
    return false;
})
```

where I tried different elements like document, body, another parent div, but still if the person is missing the uploader div, the browser opens an image in another page. I also tried to add `droppable = 'false'` on the elements in HTML markup but with the same result.

Is there any way to prevent this behavior?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/6756680/2752041. Take a look at the accepted answer, it might solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks. It is surely a duplicate (sorry for this). But Musa's answer solves the problem and it is shorter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try preventing the dragover event to

```
$(document).on('dragover drop', function(e){
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Strangely but when I was trying 'document' and 'body' it was not working.