# preventDefault(); doesn´t have any effect on a drop event

Tags: javascript, preventdefault

I have a picture-upload-`<div>` where the user can drop images. The `preventDefault();` on that `<div>`-element works fine.

But when the user drops the picture outside of the `<div>` the browser opens it.

To prevent that I added:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('body').on('drop', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

The eventhandler gets triggered, but the `preventDefault();`-action does have no effect. The browser always loads the picture.

Comment: Have you seen this similar topic here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756583/prevent-browser-from-loading-a-drag-and-dropped-file

Comment: No, thank you. That did the job!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify a default parameter. Also add a `dragover` event listener:

```
$(() => {
  $("body").on("drop", (e = event) => e.preventDefault())
      .on("dragover", (e = event) => e.preventDefault());
});
```