# How to prevent drop of audio file?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, addeventlistener

How do I listen for drop of files on a whole page? I have tried something like this to stop drop (using document, document.body, window...):

```
document.addEventListener("drop", evt => {
  evt.preventDefault(); 
  evt.stopPropagation(); 
  console.log("drop", evt);
  debugger; 
})
```

It does not work as I expected. If I drop an audio file on the page it will open and play.

Comment: The surprising solution is that you need both "drop" and "dragover", see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756583/prevent-browser-from-loading-a-drag-and-dropped-file

Comment: And that is of course a very clumsy solution. A better solutions seems to come with CSS4.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need the listener "dropend" which will listen when the drop is finished in some element.

```js
window.addEventListener("dragend", () => {
 alert("element throw in the window")
})
```

```css
#draggable {
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background: white;
  }

  .dropzone {
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    background: blueviolet;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="dropzone">
    <div id="draggable" draggable="true" ondragstart="event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain',null)">
        Drag to the white zone
    </div>
</div>
```