# How to prevent to open new tab when I drag and drop image on the Chrome browser in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have implemented drag and drop feature to my React app. but when I drag and drop image into application. it always opens new tab, but anyway the drag and drop is working well.
I need only to prevent to open new tab.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent browser from loading a drag-and-dropped file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756583/prevent-browser-from-loading-a-drag-and-dropped-file)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should add `preventDefault()` on all `dragover` and `drop` events handlers.
Example:

```
window.addEventListener("dragover",function(e){
  e = e || event;
  e.preventDefault();    <=================
},false);
window.addEventListener("drop",function(e){
  e = e || event;
  e.preventDefault();    <=================
},false);
```

[More Useful link here for React](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/reactjs-implement-drag-and-drop-feature-without-using-external-libraries-ad8994429f1a/)

[Here is the same question for drag and drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756583/prevent-browser-from-loading-a-drag-and-dropped-file)